# How to swap elements on TableLayoutPanel?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm having trouble with swapping two elements on `TableLayoutPanel` programmatically . Is it possible to swap controls housed on TableLayoutPanel during runing time ,  just like we are able to do it during `Form` designing time ?
I have 25 buttons on form, one button per `TableLayoutPanel` cell.

```
public void Bind(Cell tile1,Cell tile2)
{
    tableLayoutPanel1.SetRow(this.Controls.Find(tile1.Name,true).FirstOrDefault() as Button, tile2.Row);
    tableLayoutPanel1.SetColumn(this.Controls.Find(tile1.Name, true).FirstOrDefault() as Button, tile2.Column);

    tableLayoutPanel1.SetRow(this.Controls.Find(tile2.Name, true).FirstOrDefault() as Button, tile1.Row);
    tableLayoutPanel1.SetColumn(this.Controls.Find(tile2.Name, true).FirstOrDefault() as Button, tile1.Column);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use GetCellPosition and SetCellPosition:

```
private void SwapCells(Cell tile1, Cell tile2) {
  Control c1 = tlp.GetControlFromPosition(tile1.Column, tile1.Row);
  Control c2 = tlp.GetControlFromPosition(tile2.Column, tile2.Row);
  TableLayoutPanelCellPosition cell1 = tlp.GetCellPosition(c1);
  tlp.SetCellPosition(c1, tlp.GetCellPosition(c2));
  tlp.SetCellPosition(c2, cell1);
}
```

Comment: ,It has some properties such as Name, Row ,Column that after some calculations should set buttons name and position.

Comment: I tried your code snippet , it works fine , but would you explain what's exactly difference between your snippet and mine . it seems they are the same but actually aren't !

Comment: @sepehr My code is maybe a bit more efficient since it avoids all of those Controls.Find calls.  I think the big issue with your code is the Cell class is getting out-of-sync.  You have a cell that has Column, Row, and Name, which you have referring to the control.  Once you move the control to a new Column and Row, the Name property doesn't refer to the correct control anymore.  My two cents.